# mutate_if Error: Can't convert a list to function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to change all the values of the variable that contains word "length" after 12 hours to NA.

```
df_data <- cbind(
  seq(0, 15, by = 0.5),
  sample(seq(from = 100, to = 300, by = 10), size = 31, replace = TRUE),
  sample(seq(from = 1, to = 100, by = 9), size = 31, replace = TRUE),
  sample(seq(from = 50, to = 60, by = 2), size = 31, replace = TRUE),
  sample(seq(from = 100, to = 130, by = 1), size = 31, replace = TRUE)
) %>% as.data.frame()

colnames(df_data) <- c("hour", "a", "a_lenght", "b", "b_length")


df_new <- df_data %>%
  mutate_if(vars(contains("length")), funs(ifelse(df_data$hour > 12, NA, .)))
```

But I get a `Can't convert a list to function` error

Comment: use `mutate_at` instead of `mutate_if`. You supply a `.vars` argument (list of selected columns), but `mutate_if` needs a `.predicate` function (evaluates to TRUE/FALSE)

Comment: thanks, I also was able to fix it with `grepl` -  `mutate_if(grepl(pattern = 'length', x = names(df_data)),funs(ifelse(df_data$hour>12,NA,.)))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To summarize the comments already made:

**mutate_at uses column names** - it is most useful when you can provide a criteria that selects columns by a characteristic of the column name. 
This typically takes the form: 
mutate_at(vars(ends_with("length")), funs(...))

**mutate_if uses column content** - is most useful when you can provide a predicate function that selects columns based upon the contents of the column itself.  This typically takes the form:
mutate_if(is.integer, funs(...))

But as Galina points out, the mutate_if is versatile, and can be "tricked" into operating on column names using grepl

Comment: Is there a way to do both?  I want to mutate a specific column, but only if it is a certain class.

Comment: Of course, if you know the name of the column, you can use the simple mutate, of the form:   mutate(column_name = function).   Alternatively, you can use mutate_at, and call a user-defined function that checks the class and performs the transform.